# Kafka RBAC with API

Tags: apache-kafka, ldap, rbac

I am trying to set up a RBAC for my Kafka cluster. In the documentation [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/rbac/index.html), it says that

```
With RBAC, the user administrator can map roles to LDAP users and groups that are scoped to specific resources (role binding).
After a role binding is set using the Confluent CLI confluent iam rbac role-binding create command
```

Is it possible to do this via an API call? I am trying to assign developerRead to everyone and developerWrite to a few people that may not be based on the LDAP groups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Confluent LDAP plugin is only an enterprise, paid feature... Apache Ranger offers a free alternative and API.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the info! Did not know Confluent Kafka is the paid version of Apache Kafka. Do you know where I can get the documentation for the free API?

Comment: 1) There is no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". Confluent **Platform** is a packaged product of Apache Kafka with **plugins** (some commercial only, such as LDAP RBAC support) and enterprise support. 2) Out of the box, Kafka has no LDAP integration, only Zookeeper-based ACLs. OpenPolicyAgent and Apache Ranger are other open-source solutions for adding RBAC + ACLs to Kafka.